# Can the Kalman gain matrix contain negative values or absolute values greater than 1?

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I have implemented an EKF in a power systems application. When I run a simulation in Matlab, in some iterations of the filter I get a Kalman gain matrix (K) with negative values and/or absolute values greater than 1. In some books I have read that the Kalman gain is a real value between 0 an1.

Is this correct ? Or is it an indication that something wrong with the Kalman filter?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can answer a Kalman filtering question using lots of logic and very little math.  This is nice, because usually Kalman filtering is this big nasty blob of linear algebra and statistics all mashed together.

Take a 1-D system
$$ x_n = x_{n-1} + w_n, y_n = -0.01 x_n + v_n $$

At time \$n=0\$, let the "covariance" of \$x_0\$ be \$P = \infty\$, and let our pre-correction estimate of \$x_0 = 0\$.  Logically, we know *absolutely nothing* about \$x\$ until we measure \$y_0\$.  At that point, our *logical*, *very best* estimate of \$x_0\$ is \$-100 y_0\$.  Now if we reverse-engineer that statement, we find that \$K_0 = -100\$ for this problem, at this time.

You can do the math on this yourself, formally.  You'll probably need to take it in the limit as \$P \to \infty\$ to make the math work, but it'll work.  Trust me.   I'm an engineer; I know these things.